# Using original eigen3 library for tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, build, cmake, eigen3

I have an existing cmake C++ project and I want to use tensorflow as a shared library in it. Since my project required eigen3, I already have that library in my system (/usr/include/eigen3). Now the problem is that tensorflow also uses eigen3 but the one present in third_party folder (tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/) in its own directory. So, is it possible to use the original eigen3 library present on my system and not the one in tensorflow repository.

I checked the build scripts but I could not find anything where I can specify to use the eigen3 present in the system

Comment: I'm not using tensorflow, but I think they use a somewhat patched version of Eigen3. Until they merge their changes upstream, it is likely easiest if you use the Eigen3 library which is provided by tensorflow.